# Badge icon temporarily appeared wrong in history

Tags: bug, badges, notifications

I edited a wiki on Woodworking.SE Meta. It was an old post so I got the excavator badge for it. The notification for the badge came while I was reading a Science Fiction & Fantasy post.

So I checked my notification and saw that I got the badge for WW but it had the SF logo.

[image]

Refreshing the page then displayed the beta badge icon which was correct.

No, I don't think we need to torch and pitchfork the doors of StackOverflow to get this fixed. Just thought it was worth bringing up.

If it matters I am using Chrome Version 46.0.2490.86 m

Comment: It's loaded according to the stylesheet of the site you're currently on. And was reported somewhere.

Comment: @nicael Yeah. I figured I could not be the first person this happened to.